# What is a typical Japanese term for "fake", like in "Fake News"?

Tags: slang, colloquial-language, terminology

Besides obvious フェークニュース, is there a natural Japanese expression to express the idea of **fake**?

On the same topic, how to say **fake or shallow person**? Is there an equivalent to [plastic people](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=plastic+people) in Japanese?

Comment: "fake" is more often transcribed as フェイク, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a single word that means "fake news".

> 虚報【きょほう】

Besides, if you want the adjective only, you can use:

> 偽（の）、偽物の、嘘（の）

[虚構新聞](http://kyoko-np.net/), a counterpart of [The Onion](http://www.theonion.com/) in Japan says in the disclaimer:

> これは**嘘ニュース**です

---

For other phrases, I don't know much because I'm not familiar with colloquial English, but if I can put credit in Urban Dictionary's definitions ([fake people](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fake%20people), [plastic people](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=plastic%20people), read [shallow person](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Shallow%20person) too but I didn't get what it is), I'd say:

> 嘘（だらけ／まみれ）の人間、インチキな人間、信義のない人間、軽薄な人間

Answer (score 2):

for false rumor or fake news you can also say "dema" デマ